# Fastest way to build a list by iterating through generator objects

Tags: python, gitlab

I am using Python gitlab to get a list of gitlab projects returned as generators in batches of 100.  If a project has a tag of "snow" I want to add it to a list that will get converted to a json object.  Here is the code I have that does this:

```
gl_prj_list = gl_conn.projects.list(as_list=False)

    for p in gl_prj_list:
        if "snow" in p.tag_list:
          prj = {"id": p.id}
          prj["name"] = p.path_with_namespace
          gl_data.append(prj)

    return json.dumps(gl_data), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

So ultimately I want a result that might look like this: (only 2 of the 100 projects had the snow tag)

```
[{"id": 7077, "name": "robr/snow-cli"}, {"id": 4995, "name": "test/prod-deploy-iaas-spring-starter"}]
```

This works fine and all but seems a bit slow.  The response time is usually between 3.5-5 seconds.  And since I will have to do this over 10-20 batches I'd like to improve on the response time.

Is there a better way to check for the "snow" value in the tag_list attribute of the generator and return the result?

Comment: what does `gl_prj_list` look like?

Comment: I suspect the slowness comes from making the gitlab api calls - which is, to a large degree, outside of your control. You might want to think about an alternative solution such as caching your project data

Comment: It's a group of generator objects like this: ```<class 'gitlab.v4.objects.Project'> => {'id': 1333, 'description': '', 'name': 'Docker_Testing', 'name_with_namespace': 'Fakeman, Drake / Docker_Testing',...``` The result is actually longer than that but had to cut it short to fit in the comment. @C.Nivs

Comment: @TomDalton I sort of suspected as much.  Wanted to make sure there wasn't a more pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the bottleneck is not the API call, you can use [multiprocessing.Pool()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) for this.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(p):
    if "snow" in p.tag_list:
        return {"id":p.id, "name":p.path_with_namespace}
    return False

gl_prj_list = gl_conn.projects.list(as_list=False)

with Pool(10) as pool: #10 processes in parallel (change this with the number of cores you have available)
    gl_data = pool.map(f, gl_prj_list)

gl_data = [i for i in gl_data if i] #get rid of the False items

json.dumps(gl_data), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
```

If the bottleneck is the API call and you want to call the API multiple times, then add the call inside `f()` and use the same trick. You will call the API 10 times in parallel instead of sequentially.

Comment: You can further speed up the list comprehension using `list(filter(bool, gl_data))`